# How to define package options in a command (for reuse)?

Tags: key-value, xkeyval

I need some options of the `listings` package several times in my document. I am thus wondering if one can define (and later change) these options once somewhere in the preamble via a command/macro, for example, and use the command/macro later on if required? I tried the `keyval` package, but wasn't successful.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% write dummy R file
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.R}
f <- function(x){
  t <- exp(-x) # just some dummy example
  sqrt(t) # return value
}
\end{filecontents*}

% general listings settings
\lstset{
  language=R,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  keywords={if, else, repeat, while, function, for, in, next, break},
  otherkeywords={}
}

% define my own listings settings which frequently appear
\newcommand{\mylstset}{\setkeys{keywordstyle=\color{blue}, commentstyle=\itshape\color{red}}}

% specific listing environment
\xdefinecolor{blue}{RGB}{58, 95, 205}%
\xdefinecolor{red}{RGB}{178, 34, 34}%
\lstnewenvironment{Rinput}[1][]{%
  \lstset{\mylstset}% my listings settings
  #1% content
}{}

\begin{document}
Show \texttt{foo.R}:
\lstinputlisting[\mylstset]{foo.R}% my listings settings
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should work if you define the command without the `\setkeys` (`\newcommand{\mylstset}{keywordstyle=\color{blue}, commentstyle=\itshape\color{red}}`) and expand them first `\expandafter\lstinputlisting\expandafter[\mylstset]{foo.R}`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a solution which does not require the wrap-around of `\lstinputlisting` with `\expandafter`? Ideally, the call of `\lstinputlisting` should not be changed (by having to add `\expandafter` commands)

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to define a wrapper for `\lstinputlisting` that does the expansion for you. Try `\newcommand\myinputlisting[1][]{\expandafter\lstinputlisting\expandafter[#1]}` and then use `\myinputlisting[\mylstset]{foo.R}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to use your suggestion with `\renewcommand\lstinputlisting...`, but LaTeX hangs during compilation. Do you know why? Again, I would like to *not* change the actual call of `\lstinputlisting` since I don't want to change the code which is already working (it's a bit complicated to explain but basically a compatibility issue of several people working together).

Comment: You cannot redefine `\lstinputlisting`using itself in the definition (that causes an infinite loop). You can try `\let\myinputlisting\lstinputlisting \renewcommand\lstinputlisting[1][]{\expandafter\myinputlisting\expandafter[#1]}` (that might or might not work. I cannot test until tonight)

Comment: very good, that solved it, thanks! Let me also add, that I found related topics here: 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66355/how-to-pass-a-macro-as-a-value-for-a-key?rq=1
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/how-to-assign-a-key-of-a-package-a-key-value-of-another-package?rq=1

Comment: Should I formulate an answer from my comments?

Comment: Yes, I'll accept it then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summarizing my comments in an answer:

First thing is to define the custom setting without `\setkeys` as a simple list of key/value pairs:

```
\newcommand*\mylstset{keywordstyle=\color{blue}, commentstyle=\itshape\color{red}}
```

Now, the main problem is, that this macro needs to be expanded once before fed to `\lstinputlisting`:

```
\expandafter\lstinputlisting\expandafter[\mylstset]{foo.R}
```

As this is tedious (and is not too good a style in the document body, anyway) when one has to do it more often it might be convenient to define a wrapper for this:

```
\newcommand\myinputlisting[1][]{\expandafter\lstinputlisting\expandafter[#1]}
```

Now one can use it as follows:

```
\myinputlisting[\mylstset,otherkey=...]{foo.R}
```

It should be noted, that `\mylstset` must be the first entry in the key/value list otherwise it won't be expanded first.

Since the requirement is *not* to use a custom command but the original syntax one needs to redefine `\lstinputlisting`. For this its definition needs to be saved first and can then be used in the redefinition:

```
% save original definition of \lstinputlisting:
\let\origlstinputlisting\lstinputlisting
% renew definition of \lstinputlisting:
\renewcommand\lstinputlisting[1][]{\expandafter\origlstinputlisting\expandafter[#1]}
```

This works but it should be noted that this kind of redefinition can fail with commands that have optional arguments. A safer way is to use `\LetLtxMacro` (from the [`letltxmacro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) package) instead of `\let`.

All in all there is a better way, imho: define a custom style and use it via the `style` option:

```
% preamble:
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{keywordstyle=\color{blue}, commentstyle=\itshape\color{red}}
% document
\lstinputlisting[style=mystyle]{foo.R}
```